# Angular 17 localStorage

Tags: angular

I've tried numerous tutorials to use localStorage but no matter what I do, I get localStorage is not defined.  It appears that Angular 17 does localStorage different that older versions.  The below is my two sections but I can't find an Ang17 tutorial on using localStorage

local.token.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'

})
export class LocalService {
  name = "Das Hotel";
  
  constructor() {   }

  public saveData(key: string, value: string) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
  public getData(key: string) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key)
  }
  public removeData(key: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
  public clearData() {
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { RoomsComponent } from './rooms/rooms.component';
import { RoomsListComponent } from './rooms/rooms-list/rooms-list.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { ContainerComponent } from './container/container.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';
import { APP_CONFIG, APP_SERVICE_CONFIG } from './AppConfig/appconfig.service';
import { LocalService } from './local.token';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'hinv-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet,NgbModule,RoomsComponent, 
    RoomsListComponent, HeaderComponent, ContainerComponent, EmployeeComponent,
    HttpClientModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_SERVICE_CONFIG,
    useValue: APP_CONFIG,
  }]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'hotelapp';
  @ViewChild('name', {static: true}) name!: ElementRef;
  constructor(private localStore: LocalService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.name.nativeElement.innerText = "Huff's Hotel";
    this.localStore.saveData('name','Huff Hotel');
    this.localStore.getData('name');
  }
}
```

tried different tutorials and forum suggestions

Comment: What is expected? And what's not working? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a SSR issue. `LocalStorage` is a browser only feature.

You can run the app client side only by disabling SSR with:

Remove `prerender:true` and the `server` entry in `angular.json`

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  I've removed it but now get Failed to load url /main.server.mjs (resolved id: /main.server.mjs)

I still have this, should it be deleted?
  "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }

Comment: Yeah, remove that also !